# Link to Confluence page in JIRA comment

Tags: jira, confluence

Is there any way to reference Confluence page in JIRA comment without any additional plugins? Can accept solutions using user macros.

*Using Confluence 5.5 and JIRA 6.2.2. Confluence and Jira are wired together in Application Links*

There is nothing regarding such links in JIRA markup helper nor could I find anything elsewhere

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this automatically in comments (beyond using the [wiki renderer](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA062/Configuring+Renderers) in the comment field with [formatting](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all) to type \[h t t p://conf/display/SPC/mypage\]). You can certainly [link issues to Confluence pages](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA062/Linking+Issues#LinkingIssues-CreatingalinktoaConfluencepage). This prompts you for a comment when creating the link, but it doesn't include the link in the comment. :(

Answer (score 7):

You can use normal wiki markup inside JIRA description or comment fields. That means that the following should be rendered correctly:

- Say you have a page at http://my.server.tv/confluence/SPC/my+page.
- Insert inside the comment field something like `This is the page [my page|http://my.server.tv/confluence/SPC/my+page] ....` which will be rendered then as "This is the page [my page](http://my.server.tv/confluence/SPC/my+page) ..."
- Inside Confluence, you get on the info page of the page "my page" the backreference shown to your issue where the Confluence page was mentioned.
- Users that watch that issue (or the Confluence page) will even be notified about that.

So there is no need for additional plugins, just use normal wiki markup, but inside JIRA. And your JIRA administrator has to enable wiki markup for the whole instance.